# base package attribute in context:component-scan tag in spring 3

Tags: spring, maven

I am writing simple Hello application using maven in spring 3. I have made a `HelloWorldService` class by using `@Service` annotation. In the `applicaioncontext.xml` file giving different value to base-package attribute of `context:component-scan base-package="yyy.xxx"`. My program is running.

What is the use of base-package in `context:component-scan`?

Comment: I formatted your text, but it would look better if its title would be also a question, and not a tag cloud. Until that, you get a downvote from me. If you fixed, I will change it to an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the purpose of the second tag, `<context:component-scan>`?** Well, you need a bit of background information to understand the purpose of this tag.
Basically,say the `@Controller` annotation indicates that a particular class located at `base-package="yyy.xxx"` serves the role of a **controller**. Another example the `@RequestMapping` annotated methods to serve a web request. 
So, `component-scan base-package="yyy.xxx"` will tell the spring container via the dispatcher servlet to locate such annotated classes and methods for mapping. *But, There are plenty of more detailed explanation if you google it.*